# Setting background colour for transparent canvas/png created from Google Charts

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, background

I need help on setting the background colour of a canvas object created by using `canvg` on a `Google Charts Calendar`.

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re3nf6op/).

The image/png which is downloaded has a transparent background because the canvas had it this way. I would like to change it so that it is no longer transparent but white.I tried using `setAttribute` like so:

```
  canvas.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'position: absolute; ' +
    'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px; ' +
    'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;' +
    'backgroud-color: #fff;');
```

and also using this way: `canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';` but these attempts have failed and I haven't been able to find a good working answer.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// set to draw behind current content
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

// set background color
context.fillStyle = '#fff'; // <- background color

// draw background / rect on entire canvas
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Source: http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2011/01/setting-the-background-color-when-generating-images-from-canvas-todataurl/

Comment: it is white by default for line chart, I tried to do a different color, but it always go back to white, the reason why is I want to download the the chart with background color but it always get downloaded with transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

to be clear  -you want the circle blue?

http://jsfiddle.net/6y3ym4ov/2/ > line 4

`<circle id="circle" fill="#202020" stroke="#0A0A0A" stroke-width="4"...`

replace fill="#202020" with none / a different colour

`fill="#000099"` / `fill="blue"` / `fill="rgb(0,0,255)"`

Comment: I'm trying to change the background of this [image/PNG](http://gyazo.com/9be86809a7802c7a04fd26d80a082d71) from transparent to white. Sorry about the misguiding blue. It was meant as an example.